# Showing toast causes app to crash

Tags: java, android

My class extends `AppCompatActivity`

This is my class

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        final Button loginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
        loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click
                Login login = new Login();
                try {
                    login.getAccessCode();
                }
                catch (IOException e){
                    Log.e("LOGIN", "I got an error", e);
                }

            }
        });
    }

    public void getAccessCode() throws IOException {
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.put("a", "a");

        QuidoRestClient.post("/login/generateCode", params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                // If the response is JSONObject instead of expected JSONArray
                Log.d("LOGIN",response.toString());
                String code = "";
                try {
                    code = response.getString("code");
                }
                catch (JSONException e){

                }
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray data) {
                // If the response is JSONArray instead of expected JSONObject
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
```

I've also tried

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Login.this, text, duration);
```

I've solved the issue by calling my method directly instead of `Login login = new Login();`

Comment: where are you using this in your code?

Comment: where do you use this ? can you post the whole class ?

Comment: Have you tried using your `AppCompatActivity` as context? `Toast.makeText(this, text, duration);`

Comment: `Login login = new Login();` - Why are you doing this? That's why you're getting an NPE, either way you do it. Just call the `getAccessCode()` method directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activities are `Contexts` (or at least they inherit from `Context`). So instead of `getApplicationContext()`, simply use `this` or `YourActivity.this` in the first argument of `Toast.makeText`.

Another thing: don't do `Login login = new Login();`. Activities are instantiated by the Android runtime, not by us ! Instead, simply call `getAccessCode()` directly.

(Also, note that [`AppCompatActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) does not have any `getApplicationContext` method)

---

If the error persists, it *might* come from the fact that the `onSuccess` callback does not run in the UI thread. If this is the case, possible fixes are:

1. Don't use `Toast`, but [`Log`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) to get debug messages:

   ```
   Log.d("your tag", "your message");
   ```
2. Enclose your toast creation inside a UI thread runnable:

   ```
   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, text, duration).show();
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: I've tried Login.this and I'm getting this error



                                                                          java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: did my best with the info available at the time. Updated the answer again.